# htaccess redirect request for static files to a specific directory or remove url part from request

Tags: .htaccess

I'm working on a site which routes all requests through the index.php, but i have a problem with image, css and js includes.

My problem is:
The sites url can vary as example www.mysite.com, www.mysite.com/news/, www.mysite.com/news/something.
I generate all these pages dynamically through index.php.
My css files are linked as public/css/mycss.css.
if my url is  www.mysite.com or www.mysite.com/news/ no problem, my files are loaded, but the url is www.mysite.com/news/something obviously my files are searched in the news/public/css directory and can't be found.
Is there a good way to redirect all request for static files to the public directory.
Example:

```
/news/public/css/mycss.css
/news/public/images/myimage/myimage.jpg
/news/public/images/myimage/flags/myflag.jpg
```

to

```
public/css/mycss.css
public/images/myimage/myimage.jpg
public/images/myimage/flags/myflag.jpg
```

There could be many files and the directory structure inside public folder can vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this in the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/">
```

So that all of your relative URLs get the currect URI base applied to it.